# Rendering issue with <dc:creator> tag from Wordpress RSS2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, wordpress

I'm having issues with rendering the content of the XML  tag from my Wordpress RSS feed. Here's my code to display the last 2 posts which I draw in from the controller:

```
<h3>Check out our latest blog posts:</h3>
    <% unless @latest_blog_posts.nil? %>
      <% @latest_blog_posts.each do |post| %>
      <% if nil != post && post.respond_to?(:pubDate) %>
        <h4><%= link_to post.title, post.link, :target => "_blank" %>
        (by: <%= post.dc:creator %> - <%= time_ago_in_words(post.pubDate) %> ago)</h4>
        <%= (post.description).slice!(0, 195).html_safe %>[...]
      <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% else %>
      <p>Woops, looks like there's no posts to show. Sorry about that.</p>
    <% end %>
```

The  tag gives an error due to the ":" in the tag. I've tried using another variable and rendering the contains in a string:

```
article_author = '#{post.dc:creator}'
```

That renders "#{post.dc:creator}" in the view (I thought it would but I gave it a try anyway). Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might as well answer my own question since it's the first result in a relative Google search. Hopefully it can help someone out in the future. The xml node was being parsed as:

dc_creator

```
<%= post.dc_creator %>
```

Thanks to everyone that checked out my question and tried to help.

Comment: Bingo. Thanks for answering your own question ;)